# Share single Sidekiq between multiple Ruby on Rails Applications (Micro Services)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, microservices, sidekiq

Here I have multiple rails applications (microservices - 10), need to use one sidekiq and redis needs configure to handle across microservices.

Comment: https://brandonhilkert.com/blog/sidekiq-as-a-microservice-message-queue/

Comment: https://andresakata.medium.com/using-sidekiq-in-a-microservice-541d581fb53 This should help you get started